# Will a first gen Xbox 360 handle game releases from 2011+?

Tags: xbox-360, performance

I have had my white Xbox 360 since 2007. I have not played it for a long time and have found that you can pick them up for around £50 ($80 USD).

I plan on playing Gears of War 3, but I seem to recall my Xbox struggling with the previous generation of games (Gears of War 2, Modern Warfare 2 etc)..

Will the machine be fine, or is it about time I had an upgrade?

Comment: I like how all advantages of consoles over gaming PCs are starting to wane. Like an XBOX 360 that may or may not be an XBOX 360 capable of playing current XBOX 360 games.

Comment: @Hackworth: Except the hardware inside an Xbox 360 in 2007 and 2011 are still equivalent, modulo some details about the cooling system and hard drive size. So it's not "may or may not". It will definitely play it.

Comment: My Xbox seems fine, it runs super loud though :)

Comment: It's not a PC. It's a fixed platform. Any XBox equals any other with regards to its ability to play games, and they will all play those games with exactly the same apparent performance. Microsoft and games publishers absolutely will not get into a situation where they have to manage the support nightmare of slightly different iterations doing things slightly differently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as you don't suffer a catastrophic hardware failure, any game should work fine. In fact new 360s' CPUs clockspeeds are restricted to match the originals so that there will be no processing differences between the models.

I would recomend that you get a [hard drive for the 360](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/productID.221435400/parentCategoryID.50606600/categoryID.50790100/list.true) and install any game you play on it. Loading from the HDD significantly improves game performance.

Comment: Good news, thanks for the answer. It is crazy that you can buy one of these Xbox's for less than a SNES on ebay now :)

Comment: Well, a SNES is a well-crafted collectors' item.

Comment: They are still pretty common however. I guess they do have a cult following.

Comment: The only thing that might happen is that newer games may install updates to your XBox 360.  I had that happen a while back when I got my Kinect - one of the Kinect games installed some updates before it'd let me play.

Comment: @Brandon This happens regardless of model. All games check live when they start for updates.

Comment: @CyberSkull Those updates are actually on some disks - I'm pretty sure my 360 didn't magically get on the internet and download anything - it's an older box without a wireless card or CAT5 cable running to it. :D